# Does exist an add-in for Outlook 2013 and Outlook OnLine which runs under Outlook Android or Apple app?

Tags: iphone, outlook, add-in

Microsoft says than you can develop an add-in for Outlook which runs on Outlook 2013, Outlook OnLine and Outlook apps.
but on the Office Store, there is no add-in which can be used on Outlook apps.

Furthermore, add-ins for Outlook Online can not be used using Safari or Google Chrome on IOS. They are available only under Windows (Desktop).

Has someone succeeded to develop an add-in for all Outlook ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

For outlook, you develop a 'mail add in' which will show up in Outlook, Outlook online etc. Mail add-ins are slightly different to other types of office add-in in that they need to be deployed to an Exchange server which is either on premise or via office 365.

See the docs on mail add-ins here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj220072.aspx

I'm not sure whether mail apps work on IOS or Android just yet, I don't think they are compatible yet.